# Task ownership in Factory-Processor model

Tags: c++, concurrency

Factory supplies Tasks of different types to Processor asynchronously. Processor doesn't know details of Tasks and executes them via known Interface. Dynamic allocation is prohibited due to performance reasons. Factory should not own Tasks because otherwise Processor would need to inform Factory when he finishes execution of Task to do the cleanup. Processor should know only Interface, but not Tasks themselves. Processor may own Tasks as opaque objects while he processes them.

One possible solution is: store all kinds of Tasks inside the union of "Interface & padding buffer". Please, consider the following working example (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Interface
{
    virtual void execute() {}
};

union X
{
    X() {}
    Interface i;
    char padding[1024];
    template <class T>
    X& operator= (T &&y)
    {
        static_assert (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(padding), "X capacity is not enough!");
        new (padding) T(y);
    }
};

struct Task : public Interface
{
    Task() : data(777) {}
    virtual void execute() { std::cout << data << std::endl; }
    int data;
};

int main()
{
    Task t;
    X x;
    x = std::move(t);
    Interface *i = &x.i;
    i->execute();
};
```

The snippet works well (prints 777). But are there any dangers (like virtual inheritance) in such approach? Maybe any better solution is possible?

Comment: See: [`std::aligned_union` (en.cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union). It is designed to be used together with placement new and explicit destructor call.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer.**

See: [`std::aligned_union` (en.cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union). It is designed to be used together with placement new and explicit destructor call.

---

**Below is the earlier answer, now retracted.**

---

From the design perspective,

- Avoiding dynamic allocation seems a drastic requirement. It requires some extraordinary justification.
- In case one does not trust the standard allocator for any reason, one could still implement a custom allocator, in order to have full control of its behavior.
- If there is a class or method that "owns" all instances of everything: all Factories, all Processors, and all Tasks (as is the case in your `main()` method), then it is not necessary to copy anything. Just pass references or pointers around, since this "class or method that owns everything" will take care of object lifetime.

---

My answer is only applicable to the question about "memcpy".

I do not try to cover the issue of memcpy-ing between "Task which has Interface as *base class*, and X which has Interface as *member*". This doesn't seem universally valid for all of the C++ compilers, but I don't know offhand which C++ compilers would fail this code.

---

Short answer, which is applicable to all C++ compilers:

- To use [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) on a type, the type needs to be [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable).

Currently, trivially copyable lists "no virtual functions" as one of the necessary conditions, so the "according to the spec" answer is that your struct `Task` is not trivially copyable.

---

The longer, non-standard answer is whether your particular compiler will synthesize the struct and the machine code that would be *effectively* copyable (i.e. without ill-effects), despite the C++ specification saying no. Obviously this answer will be compiler-specific, and will depend on a lot of circumstances (such as optimization flags and minor code changes).

Remember that compiler optimization and code generation can change from version to version. There is no guarantee that the next version of the compiler will behave exactly the same.

---

To give an example of something that would be likely to be unsafe for memcpy-ing between two instances, consider:

```
struct Task : public Interface
{
    Task(std::string&& s) 
        : data(std::move(s)) 
    {}
    virtual void execute() { std::cout << data << std::endl; }
    std::string data;
};
```

The reason this is problematic is that, for sufficiently long strings, `std::string` will allocate dynamic memory to store its content. If there are two instances of `Task`, and memcpy is used to copy its bytes from one instance to another instance (which would have copied over the internal fields of the `std::string` class), their pointers will point to the same address, and therefore their destructors will both try to delete the same memory, leading to undefined behavior. In addition, if the instance that was being overwritten had an earlier string value, the memory will not be freed.

Since you have said that "dynamic allocation is prohibited", my guess is that you will not be using `std::string` or anything similar, instead opting to write C-like code exclusively. So this concern may not be relevant to you.

---

Speaking of "low level C-like code", here is my idea:

```
struct TaskBuffer
{
    typedef void (*ExecuteFunc) (TaskBuffer*);
    ExecuteFunc executeFunc;
    char padding[1024];
};

void ProcessMethod(TaskBuffer* tb)
{
    (tb->executeFunc)(tb);
}
```

Comment: In fact, there is no need for object to be trivially copyable to be copied contiguously (at last, std::vector can store them). Because shallow copy is enough and preferred! The problem my occur if rvalue `y` will destruct it's data. I've checked the above example, destructor is called only on `t`, but not `y` (of course, `y` is a reference, but there must be corresponding temporary)! To ensure data safety, `y` may be ripped from owning the data after `memcpy` is done.

Comment: @midenok in your code example, it does not use memcpy to copy between two instances of `Task`. It copies from one `Task` into a byte array. The function that performs that copying knows practically nothing about `y`, so it won't be calling `y`'s destructor. In your experiment, `t`'s destructor is actually called at the end of the `main()` method (scope), which is an example of scope-bound object destruction.

Comment: Of course `y` is a reference, and destructor is not called on reference. But `std::move` was supposed to create a **temporary**... F.ex., copy semantics (`T y` signature instead of `T &&y`) leads to `y.~Task()` call. This must be my lack of knowledge of move semantics... So, if move semantics was designed to not destruct a temporary, then everything is good as it is!

Comment: Passing in `(T y)` is also known as "passing by value" (when T is constrained *not to be* a reference), and "passing by value" involves copying. When a function receives a passed-by-value argument, the function will call the argument's destructor at the end (if a destructor exists).

Comment: Avoiding dynamic allocation is a *must* for fast handling network connections, otherwise server capacity will degrade drastically. There can't be a class that owns all Tasks, because Factory produces them (per network connection). Task lifetime is short (usually equal to 1 chunk of data on single connection). I don't understand why you mention machine code to be copyable? I don't understand, because machine code (apart from residing in totally different memory segment) is meant to be never copied (except malicious software).

Comment: What I mean about machine code is that one can read the machine code that is generated by the compiler to determine whether that code would execute correctly. In other words, while the C++ specification specifies what is "undefined behavior", a person who looks at the machine code will be able to tell whether the machine code will actually cause "incorrect operation" or not.

Comment: But since the object can be pushed to `std::vector` the code will be valid. Isn't it? In other words, object is always allocated on contiguous chunk, no matter whether it is 'trivially copyable' or not!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to involve both an unnecessary copy operation, and making assumptions about the layout of your objects in memory that are not guaranteed to be correct in all circumstances. It further invokes undefined behaviour by using memcpy to copy an object with virtual methods, which is explicitly disallowed by the c++ spec. It also has the potential to cause confusion over when object destructors run.

I would use an arrangement like this:

class Processor has an array of buffers, each of which is large enough to contain any defined subclass of your task interface. It has two methods used in submitting tasks:

- one to return a pointer to a currently available buffer
- one to submit a job

The job interface is extended with a requirement to track the pointer to the buffer that contains it (which will be supplied as a constructor parameter), and has a method to return that pointer.

Submitting a new task is now done like this:

```
void * buffer = processor.getBuffer();
Task * task = new (buffer) Task(buffer);
processor.submitJob(task);
```

(this could be simplified using a template method in Processor if required). Then, the processor simply executes jobs, and when it's done with them it asks them for their buffer, runs their destructor, and adds the buffer back into its free buffer list.

Comment: Just replaced memcpy() with placement new. Looks better now, thanks to you! But further suggestions are not so perfect: memory pool requires extra logic (freelist maintenance, concurrency protection), which is way too much slower than just copying of Task (it meant to be a small object, ideally just 1 file-descriptor).

Comment: @midenok (1) Memory pool is not necessarily implemented using freelist. A bitmap will also work. (2) Memory pool can be designed to be thread-local.

Comment: @rwong (1) Then bitmap is "freelist". Here is no point in discussing of how it can be implemented. (2) TLS is "concurrency protection" and also slower than regular memory. No matter what implementation is, the result will be much slower. (3) How much the pool should be? If it will exceed, what then? It creates a lot of extra complications (which will lead to problems and extra maintenance) where we can just work on stack.

Comment: @midenok - tls is not noticeably slower than regular memory on modern platforms (see:  https://testbit.eu/thread-local-storage-benchmark/). And I do question where your storage is coming from if it is neither finite in size nor dynamically allocated...? Storage on the stack cannot have indeterminate lifetime, which would seem to be required here, unless you are using a thread-per-request model (which is known not to scale to the kind of levels you must be anticipating if you expect dynamic allocation to be problematically slow).